# Filtering actual code changes in a pull request

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I find it quite frustrating when there is a PR that I need to review and it includes file formatting changes. It's not that bad for a smaller PR, however, when its a little bigger PR and you are trying to hunt actual code changes, it becomes quite frustrating. Is there any tool or way to cut down on clutter and only filter actual code change ??

Comment: Most diffing tools have a setting to ignore whitespace changes. Maybe this is sufficient for your needs?

Comment: You're solving this problem in the wrong place. Automate linting against an agreed style guide to minimise non-functional changes to the code (not to mention the time spent choosing how exactly to lay it out).

Comment: If it's more than simple whitespace changes, I agree with jonrsharpe. Establish a coding standard for your project, use a tool to apply it across the whole project, and require it in future changes using an automated PR check. For example, Ruby has rubocop and the style check can be done by a service such as Code Climate.

Comment: @Schwern I completely agree with applying a consistent style across a project. It doesn't exactly solve the problem because as the PRs come in to standardize the style, the OPs concern will continue and need to be addressed in the near term.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice There's one big automated style change PR and then it's done. I don't know of any other solution. Without using a special language-aware diff program, and I'm not aware of any, Git cannot ignore style changes beyond white-space.

Comment: @Schwern Good point. That's better than what I had in mind doing it piecemeal as you work on code. Which now that I type it outloud sounds terrible.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice And yet that's how so many projects do it.